# Splitting a string in java twice

Tags: java, arrays, split

I want to split the string : "Attack Potion[1]" so that i am left with only the number which is "1" in this case.

I tryed this but it didn't work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("" + splitter("Attack Potion[1]"));

}

public static int splitter(String i) {
    String[] splitOne = i.split("[");
    String[] splitTwo = splitOne[1].split("]");
    int extractedNumber = Integer.parseInt(splitTwo[0]);
    return extractedNumber;
}
```

I want the output to be:

```
1
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the `[` and `]` characters since [they're special characters in regular expressions.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)  You'll need two slashes since a single backslash is used to denote an escape sequence of some sort (ie: \n for newline, etc).

Try the following:

```
String[] splitOne = i.split("\\[");
String[] splitTwo = splitOne[1].split("\\]");
```

Alternatively, you could use [Pattern.quote](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29).

Example:

```
String[] splitOne = i.split(Pattern.quote("["));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should replace your calls to `String#split("[")` by some calls to `split("\\[")`.

Why do I do `split("\\[")`?

`String#split` works with a **regex** but `[` is not a standard character inside a regex.
For this to happen, it needs to be **escaped**, using `\[`. However, in Java String, `\` is not a standard character either, and needs to be escaped as well.
Thus, just to split on `[`, the Java String used is `"\\["`.

Answer (score 1):

`split` uses regex as parameter and in regex `[` or `]` are special characters which creates character classes like `[a-z]`. To make them simple literals you need to escape them. You can do it with `"\\["`, `\\]` (actually you don't have to escape `]` if it doesn't have unclosed metacharacter `[` before. So you can try

```
String[] splitOne = i.split("\\[");
String[] splitTwo = splitOne[1].split("]");
```

or even use `|` (means OR) and add `]` to your first split

```
String[] splitOne = i.split("\\[|]");
int extractedNumber = Integer.parseInt(splitOne[1]);
//                                     ^-use result from splitOne
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use this regex:

```
String string = "Attack Potion[100]";
System.out.println(string.replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
```

**Output:**

```
100
```

Answer (score 0):

Delimiting worked for me.

```
String[] splitOne = i.split("\\[");
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to escape like this ("\]"),("\[");

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("" + splitter("Attack Potion[1]"));

    }

    public static int splitter(String i) {
        String[] splitOne = i.split("\\[");
        String[] splitTwo = splitOne[1].split("\\]");
        int extractedNumber = Integer.parseInt(splitTwo[0]);
        return extractedNumber;
    }
```

**output**

```
1
```

Answer (score 0):

For regex expressions, you have to escape the `[` and `]` characters because they are part of regex delimiters. So you would need to do this:

```
String[] splitOne = i.split("\\[");
String[] splitTwo = splitOne[1].split("\\]");
```

However, you don't even need to split it a second time. If you're sure that the number after `[` is only one digit, you could simply do this:

```
public static int splitter(String i) {
    String[] splitOne = i.split("\\[");
    int extractedNumber = Integer.parseInt(splitOne[1].substring(0,1));
    return extractedNumber;
}
```

Using substring to only parse the first digit.

Answer (score 0):

Check the snippet below. It should work.

```
String pattern = "(.*\\[)(\\d+)(\\])";
Pattern regc = Pattern.compile(pattern);
String tomatch = "Attack Potion[1]";
Matcher matcher = regc.matcher(tomatch);
if (matcher.find() && matcher.groupCount() == 3){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
}
```

Basically, it is better to use regular expressions for doing such stuffs.